# Twilio webchat 3.0 ability to end webchat after specific time period

Tags: flexbox, twilio, twilioflexwebchat

We are using Flex account and currently have a mobile app chat. it was implemented using conversation sdk. Now planning to implement webchat for our website using the same flex account and without interrupting existing mobile app chat.

We implemented separate workflow and studio flow for Webchat in the existing flex account and workspace using Webchat 3.0. Now we have a requirement to end the customer's chat/conversation after 10 minutes. How can we do that without interrupting/changing the existing mobile app flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available out-of-the-box. But you can implement yourself using a timer or a queue. The chat begins, you start a timer or add a work item to a queue, wait for the timer to go off or the queue item to meet your business rules, then use the Twilio Messaging API to programmatically [update the conversation status to "closed"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#update-conversation).

Comment: This worked for me. We used queue solution